# poisson distribution change max limit

Tags: distribution, poisson

I use poisson_distribution with a mean value of 500, the problem is that after 1200 itterations the distributin is between 423-571, how can i change the max limit for example the results to be from 1 to 4.000.000 but with a mean value of 500?

Here is my code:

```
unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
std::default_random_engine generator (seed);
int mean = 500; 
std::poisson_distribution<int> distribution_2(mean);
array_of_elements[pos_in_array].time_of_arrival = distribution_2(generator);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the spread of a Poisson distribution, the variance is identical to the mean. Since you have a mean of 500 the standard deviation is about 22.4.  Practically speaking, you're just not going to see outcomes below 400 or above 600, and that's indeed what you observed with your 1200 iterations.

If you want that much of a range, you'll need something other than a Poisson distribution.  In fact, given [Markov's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_inequality) it would be pretty darn hard to get a distribution of positive quantities with a mean of 500 that can go as high as 4 million.  A 4 million can occur no more than one time per 8000 trials, and if the minimum outcome is 1 rather than 0, 4 millions must be even rarer.